# SUM(COUNTIFS()) with multiple OR array constant in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Need a count of "Apple" or "Orange" that are either "Eaten" or "Half Eaten" on a month-to-month basis. To be used for Google Sheets.

Currently, `=SUM(COUNTIFS(H:H,A2,J:J,{"Eaten","Half Eaten"},I:I,{"Apple";"Orange"}))` and `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(H:H,A2,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(I:I,{"Apple","Orange"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(J:J,{"Eaten","Not Eaten"},0)))` doesn't seem to work. Interestingly, the first formula works on Excel.

Test sheet here for reference - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ch3M2mLMWur9VW9G8i4NsFnzwj1w1d1JCrkj7FpMrZY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function with `matches` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try `QUERY()` function with `matches` operator.

```
=QUERY(H2:J22,"select H, count(I) 
where (I matches 'Apple|Orange') and (J matches 'Eaten|Half Eaten') 
group by H
label H 'Month'")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Harun24hr! Is it possible to do this without the =QUERY()?

Comment: @qazamy what is wrong with QUERY?

Comment: @qazamy Yes, possible. Query result is correct or not?

Comment: @user11222393 The software clone that I'll be using this on doesn't support QUERY().

Comment: @Harun24hr Yes, the result output from the QUERY() formula is correct.

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag Google Sheets as I believe there will be more differences not just query

Comment: @qazamy Check your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

*[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ch3M2mLMWur9VW9G8i4NsFnzwj1w1d1JCrkj7FpMrZY/edit#gid=308268804):*

```js
=index(let(Σ,text(edate(,sequence(12)),"mmmm"),
             hstack(Σ,countifs(C:C,Σ,--regexmatch(D:D,"Apple|Orange"),1,--regexmatch(E:E,"^(Half )?Eaten"),1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like the software clone that I'm using doesn't support some of the formulas as it spits out this error - "Wrong number of arguments to INDEX. Expected at least 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments."

Answer (score 0):

Answer as provided by user @Harun24hr:
`=IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER($I$2:$I,($I$2:$I="Apple")+($I$2:$I="Orange"),($J$2:$J="Eaten")+($J$2:$J="Half Eaten"),$H$2:$H=Q3)),0)`

Seems like ROW() can be replaced with COUNTA().